# Using structured references, how do I link two Excel tables with different starting rows?

Tags: excel, structured-references

All of the examples I've seen of referencing one table data in another, e.g.
`=table1[@Table1Column]`
assume that the tables start on the same row.

In my case, I have `table1` that is starting on row 5, and another `table2` on a different sheet starting on row 10.  I want to display particular columns from `table1` in `table2`.  The user might wish to add or remove rows above the tables, so I can't just hardcode 5 rows of offset.

If I simply use the structured reference, `=table1[@Table1Column]` it displays row 10 of `table1` rather than the *first* row of `table 1`.  So I'm missing 5 rows of data.

I could use VLOOKUP and ROW() to offset the starting rows, but I thought the point of structured references was to get us away from using these methods to incorporate content from one table into another.

If it's best to use Relationships or Pivot Tables or something let me know, I just need a pointer in the right direction.  Thank you!

Comment: Try `=OFFSET(Table1[Table1Column],0,0,5,1)`

Comment: I read that using INDEX is preferable to OFFSET as it doesn't re-calculate every time a value on the sheet is changed.  Is this true?  I'm starting to see performance hits for the size of data I'm working with so I'm trying to code smarter

Answer (score 3):

```
=INDEX(Table1, ROW() - ROW(Table2[#Headers]), [ColumnIndex])
```